# How to verify signature with pss padding?

Tags: openssl

We created debug public and private keys for RSA sign.
And we generate sha256 hash and save in cp1.bin.
Then we try to verify signature but always failed.
If we don't use pss padding, the verify command will pass.
Anyone can please help to comment?

Thanks

C:\Project\pkc>openssl pkeyutl -sign -in cp1.bin -inkey pvt_dbg.pem  -out sig1.bin -pkeyopt digest:sha256 -pkeyopt rsa_padding_mode:pss -pkeyopt rsa_pss_saltlen:32

C:\Project\pkc>openssl pkeyutl -verify -in cp1.bin -sigfile sig1.bin -pkeyopt rsa_padding_mode:pss -pkeyopt rsa_pss_saltlen:32 -pubin -inkey pub_dbg.pem
Signature Verification Failure

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 6):

Can run verify command successfully now.

```
$ openssl pkeyutl -sign \
  -in hashOut.bin -inkey pvt_dbg.pem \
  -out sig1.bin \
  -pkeyopt digest:sha256 \
  -pkeyopt rsa_padding_mode:pss \
  -pkeyopt rsa_pss_saltlen:-1
```

Then

```
$ openssl pkeyutl -verify \
  -in cp1.bin -sigfile sig1.bin \
  -pkeyopt rsa_padding_mode:pss \
  -pubin -inkey pub_dbg.pem \
  -pkeyopt rsa_pss_saltlen:-1 \
  -pkeyopt digest:sha256
```

Comment: On Ubuntu with OpenSSL 1.0.1f, all `pkeyopt`s must be towards the end or the following error is thrown: `-pkeyopt command before -inkey`. Also, I used the following command to generate the hash: `openssl dgst -sha256 -binary payload.bin > cp1.bin`

Comment: @akhan saved me a lot of headache

Comment: Yes, it avoids the error message:
Error: The input data looks too long to be a hash

Thank you @akhan